# A question on an alternative Totient Function-like construction

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Euler's Totient (or phi) function $\phi(n)$ is a counting function that counts all the numbers co-prime and less than some natural number $n$.
This is equivalent to finding all natural numbers $a_i < n$ such that $\gcd(a_i,n)=1$.
My question is this:

> Define $\psi(n,b)$ as a counting function that counts the numbers co-prime to some number $n$ in the interval $(n,n+b]$. Depending on the choice of $n$ and $b$, is there a way to quickly evaluate $\psi(n, b)$?

One choice is obvious; $n+1$ will be co-prime to $n$.

Comment: Much like with $\phi$, your function can be evaluated quickly, given the factorization of $n$. Short of that, no.